# Problem with import / export ts modules in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

So I tried to make a webpack config for a website which is using typescript. Everything works but when I want to import some ts file which is not an entry I am getting an error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../module' in '/Users/user/Projects/Node/project/src/script'
```

How can I fix this? I guess webpack don't know about a file I try to import but what I should do? I am learning webpack and I couldn't find anything on the web.

folder structure:

```
/src
 /util
  -module.ts
 /script
  -index.ts
 ...
```

reason (index.ts):

```
import { sth } from "../util/module"; // <-----------
console.log(sth);
```

module:

```
export const sth = "Hello World!";
```

webpack config:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const generateEntry = () => {
  const entry = {};
  const entryDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "src/script");

  fs.readdirSync(entryDir).forEach((file) => {
    const filename = file.split(".")[0];
    entry[filename] = path.resolve(__dirname, "src/script", file);
  });

  return entry;
};

const generateTemplates = () => {
  const templates = [];
  const templatesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "src/templates");

  fs.readdirSync(templatesDir).forEach((file) => {
    const filename = file.split(".")[0];
    templates.push(
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/templates", file),
        chunks: [filename]
      })
    );
  });

  return templates;
};

module.exports = {
  entry: generateEntry(),
  output: {
    publicPath: "",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "script/[name].[contenthash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/i,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          outputPath: "static",
          name: "[name].[contenthash].[ext]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: false,
    port: 8654
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "style/[name].[contenthash].css"
    })
  ].concat(generateTemplates())
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So adding

```js
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts']
}
```

inside webpack config fixed this for me :))))))